# What about be a good node npm module to do LDAP queries?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking to build a wrapper app to search/create new LDAP IDs in Node with Express. Which module would be good for this purpose? I'm not looking to authenticate at this point, but that functionality (if it doesn't come in the way, would be great -- to add on in the future).

I'm too new to Node, so learning as I start my first project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ldapjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapjs). It does pretty much whatever you expect from an ldap client (search, adding, deleting entries and more).

If you want to setup a local LDAP server for development purposes, check [this](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) out. It is lightweight and easy to setup.

If you want to add auth later, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth) module will help. It adds a LDAP strategy for passport. But you need to be acquainted with [passport](http://passportjs.org/docs) functionality first. It is pretty much the NodeJS standard for auth.